# $name displayed on page

Tags: sitecore7, sitecore-mvc

$name token is displayed on page content instead of item's title text.

Item has standard values defined and ofcourse uses $name for title place.

I investigated the versions of the item and latest version is in use. Application uses only one language en-US and developed using sitecore 7.2 mvc and also webforms.

Rebuild indexes, but the issue still exists.  Any leads on this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and include details of what you have tried.

Comment: Did you delete __Standard Values item and then create it again?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can not delete them as lot of the items are associated with that template. And this issue is in production only.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is happening while creating new items also. If yes then check your logs there may be some error which can help.  If it is working fine then it may be happening because you have created your items before creating your _standardvalues item. In this case you can write a custom script/code to fix it. You can also try this https://github.com/rauljmz/Sitecore.Rocks.ReplaceMacros .

Comment: Its not happening while creating new items. For now issue is solved by creating new item and deleting the old one. But if this persists again and again while creating item then would need to identify the actual root cause.